# No new line before form

Tags: php, html

First my code:

```
<?php
echo 'Hello
<FORM ACTION="uebung3.php" METHOD="post">
<P>
<LABEL FOR="vorname">Vorname: </LABEL>  
          <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="vorname">
<LABEL FOR="nachname">Nachname: </LABEL> 
          <INPUT TYPE="textarea" NAME="nachname">
<LABEL FOR="email">E-Mail: </LABEL>   
          <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="email">
<INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="geschlecht" VALUE="Maskulin"> Maskulin
<INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="geschlecht" VALUE="Feminin"> Feminin
<input type="password" for="pw" NAME="PW"> 
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Absenden"> 
<INPUT TYPE="reset" VALUE="Zurücksetzen">
</P>
</FORM>
';
?>
```

So if i run that on my xampp-Server, it shows a "Hello" and the Form in a new line.
What must I do that all this is written in one line?

Thanks

Comment: Written on one line or rendered on one line? Seems like a CSS question.. not php.

Comment: Remove the `<P>` element. It's block level.

Comment: Even removing `<p>` tags, your `hello` will still appear on a seperate line. This is because it is outside your form. Put it inside `<form>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `<p>` element and display the form inline.

```
<?php
echo 'Hello
<FORM ACTION="uebung3.php" METHOD="post" style="display:inline">
<LABEL FOR="vorname">Vorname: </LABEL>  
          <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="vorname">
<LABEL FOR="nachname">Nachname: </LABEL> 
          <INPUT TYPE="textarea" NAME="nachname">
<LABEL FOR="email">E-Mail: </LABEL>   
          <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="email">
<INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="geschlecht" VALUE="Maskulin"> Maskulin
<INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="geschlecht" VALUE="Feminin"> Feminin
<input type="password" for="pw" NAME="PW"> 
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Absenden"> 
<INPUT TYPE="reset" VALUE="Zurücksetzen">
</FORM>
';
?>
```

Comment: This works also, because of the `style="display:inline"` Good answer Ryan.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the paragraph break '<P>'

Comment: didn't fix it, see Ryan's answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You should really use a heredoc for this type of HTML output in PHP. Technically, the `<p>` tag should be around the `Hello`, not the form. You're looking for something like:

```
<?php

echo <<<EOT
Hello
<FORM ACTION="uebung3.php" METHOD="post">
<LABEL FOR="vorname">Vorname: </LABEL>  
          <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="vorname">
<LABEL FOR="nachname">Nachname: </LABEL> 
          <INPUT TYPE="textarea" NAME="nachname">
<LABEL FOR="email">E-Mail: </LABEL>   
          <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="email">
<INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="geschlecht" VALUE="Maskulin"> Maskulin
<INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="geschlecht" VALUE="Feminin"> Feminin
<input type="password" for="pw" NAME="PW"> 
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Absenden"> 
<INPUT TYPE="reset" VALUE="Zurücksetzen">
</FORM>
EOT;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Even by removing `<p>` tags, your `hello` will still appear on a seperate line. This is because it is outside your `<form>` tag.

Put it inside `<form>` like this, while removing the `<p>` tags:

```
<?php
echo '<FORM ACTION="uebung3.php" METHOD="post">Hello
<LABEL FOR="vorname">Vorname: </LABEL>  
          <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="vorname">
<LABEL FOR="nachname">Nachname: </LABEL> 
          <INPUT TYPE="textarea" NAME="nachname">
<LABEL FOR="email">E-Mail: </LABEL>   
          <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="email">
<INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="geschlecht" VALUE="Maskulin"> Maskulin
<INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="geschlecht" VALUE="Feminin"> Feminin
<input type="password" for="pw" NAME="PW"> 
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Absenden"> 
<INPUT TYPE="reset" VALUE="Zurücksetzen">

</FORM>
';
?>
```

Comment: well, you're absoloutely right, but I can't change it in my code as it's just a short form...

Comment: Ok, I understand. Thanks for the heads-up. Ryan's answer is clearly the best method. @m00lti